# Directly saving a figure to disk without rendering first on the screen

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I currently have code like the following:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pylab 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm    
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon  
import numpy as np

...

# Read my image
img = matplotlib.image.imread(p_image)

# Render it, move the coordinates' origin to the upper left corner
plt.imshow(np.flipud(img), cmap=cm.Greys_r,origin='upper')

# Overlay a polygon
p = Polygon( zip(xs,ys), alpha=0.2)
plt.gca().add_artist(p)

# Save it to disk
plt.savefig(p_image_output)
```

How can I directly save this figure to disk **without rendering it first on the screen?** (notice that I would like the figure to keep the properties specified in the three arguments that I pass to `imshow`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using `ipython --pylab`, the figure should only appear on screen if you do a `show()` or `draw()`. If you don't want it to be shown on the screen, just make sure you are not doing any of those calls.

Alternatively, you can use a non-interactive backend in matplotlib. For example, the `Agg` backend. Just make sure you have the following set in your `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` file:

```
backend      : Agg
```

Keep in mind that using this backend you'll never see anything on screen. If you use `ipython`, you can keep the configuration file and have an interactive backend by calling `--pylab` with a specific backend. For example:

```
ipython --pylab=qt
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to set the `matplotlib` backend to something without interactive support. A standard way is to insert the following lines before you start using or importing from other parts of `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

The standard backend is `TkAgg`, which uses "agg" ("anti-grain geometry") rendering with a Tk interactive event loop. Using `Agg` does the same type of figure rendering, but without showing anything on the screen.

Note that, once you change the backend, `matplotlib` may not be able to switch it back. So this works best if you know you don’t want to plot anything on the screen in this script.

Comment: this didnt work for me the figure still pops up