# Saving to disk directly with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to save my figures to disk without rendering them on the screen and without having to change my rendering backend.

I tried the instructions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575659/directly-saving-a-figure-to-disk-without-rendering-first-on-the-screen), namely avoiding calling `fig.show()` nor `fig.draw()` and just calling `fig.savefig`, but I noticed that the mere statement `fig = plt.figure()` already opens a figure on the screen.

How can I save a figure to disk without having to render it, and without having to change my backend?

Comment: `plt.ioff()`  Why don't you just use a non-interactive backend?  And almost all of the `plt.*` commands have an implicit `plt.draw()` in them so you _are_ calling it.

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell I realize I had an `ion()` on my code. If you write that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pyplot` has an interactive functionality which will automatically call `draw()` after most `plt.*` calls for you.

`draw` is not automatically called  if you *don't* go through the state machine interface (ex `gca().plot(...)` would not automatically redraw, but `plt.plot(...)` would).

See the [code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L2982), the important function in `draw_if_interactive`.

This can be turn off via `plt.ioff()` or by not calling `plt.ion()` (`ipython --pylab` automatically turns it on for you).

[doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ioff)

Comment: At least in some recent versions of Matplotlib, it is not true that "`draw()` is automatically called after each call" in interactive mode, so this should be taken with a grain of salt. There are [interesting points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130341/exact-semantics-of-matplotlibs-interactive-mode-ion-ioff) on this in one of my StackOverflow questions.